# Image doesn't change in child activity using Activitygroup in android

Tags: android, android-tabs, activitygroup

In my app, I' using Tab. There are three tabs. In which 3rd tab is Activity group which has two activities. In first activity, there are two options for user. User can choose image from camera or from gallery. After selecting an image, user should move to child activity, which will display selected image in that activity. Till this app is working fine. But only problem here I'm facing is, image is not being cleared when I move back to parent activity from child activity. Means once I choose image from gallery/camera, user moves to child activity, and image is being displayed in child activity. Now when I press back button from child activity, user moves back to parent activity and again if user selects different image from galley/camera, that different image is not there in child activity. The previous image is there in child activity. Below is my code.

### ABCGroup.java

```
public class ABCGroup extends ActivityGroup{

public static ABCGroup group;
private ArrayList<View> history;
View view;
int column_index;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.history = new ArrayList<View>();
    group = this;
    view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("ParentActivity", new Intent(ABCGroup.this, Tab1.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY)).getDecorView();
    replaceView(view);
 }

public void replaceView(View v) {

    history.add(v);
    setContentView(v);
}

public void back() {  


    if(history.size() > 0) 
    {  

        history.remove(history.size()-1);
        if(history.size()<=0)
        {
            finish();
        }
        else
        {
            setContentView(history.get(history.size()-1));

        }
    }
    else 
    {  
        finish(); 
    }  

}

@Override  
public void onBackPressed() {  
    ABCGroup.group.back();
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
        ABCGroup.group.back();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    InputStream stream = null;
    if (requestCode == Tab1.REQUEST_ID && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

         try
         {
            stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
            Bitmap original = null;
            original= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            String selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);

        }

         catch (Exception e) 
         {
                e.printStackTrace();
         }
        if (stream != null) 
        {
            try 
            {
                stream.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }



    if (requestCode == 3 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) 
    {

        getContentResolver().notifyChange(Tab1.mUri, null);
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

        try 
        {
            Tab1.mPhoto = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, Tab1.mUri);
            Second.bmp = Tab1.mPhoto;
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            Tab1.mPhoto.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
            File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/ABCGroup");
            String mydate = java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Time :" + mydate, 5000).show();
            if(!direct.exists())
            {
                direct.mkdir();
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator + "/ABCGroup/image" + mydate +".jpg");
                file.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(file);
                fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                fo.close();
             }

         else
            {
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator + "/ABCGroup/image" + mydate +".jpg");
                file.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(file);
                fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                fo.close();
            }

            View mview = ABCGroup.group.getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("activity3", new Intent(ABCGroup.this, Second.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY)).getDecorView();
            replaceView(mview);
        }

        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}


   public String getPath(Uri uri) {
       String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
       Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
       column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
       cursor.moveToFirst();

       SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
       SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
       editor.putString("data", cursor.getString(column_index) );
       editor.commit();

       View mview = ABCGroup.group.getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("activity3", new Intent(ABCGroup.this, Second.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY)).getDecorView();
       replaceView(mview);


       return cursor.getString(column_index);
   }

   public void onResume()
   {
       super.onResume();
       column_index = 0;
   }

}
```

### Tab1.java

```
public class Tab1 extends ActivityGroup {

    Button gallery, camera;
    private ArrayList<View> myActivityHistory;
    ImageView iv;

    private static final int TAKE_PICTURE = 3;
    public static final int REQUEST_ID = 1;
    private static final int HALF = 2;
    public static Uri mUri;
    public static Bitmap mPhoto;
    int i = 0;
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.tab1);
         View viewToLoad = LayoutInflater.from(Tab1.this.getParent()).inflate(R.layout.tab1, null);
         Tab1.this.setContentView(viewToLoad);
        myActivityHistory = new ArrayList<View>();

        gallery = (Button)viewToLoad.findViewById(R.id.gallery);
        camera = (Button)viewToLoad.findViewById(R.id.camera);
        iv = (ImageView)viewToLoad.findViewById(R.id.iv);
        gallery.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    ABCGroup.group.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_ID);
                }
            });

            camera.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
                    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),  "photo.jpg");
                    i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                    mUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
                    ABCGroup.group.startActivityForResult(i, TAKE_PICTURE);
                }
            });
    }



    public void replaceContentView(String id, Intent newIntent) 
    {
        View mview = ABCGroup.group.getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(id,newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)).getDecorView();
        ABCGroup.group.replaceView(mview);
    }


}
```

### Second.java

```
public class Second extends Activity {

    public static Bitmap bmp;
    Bitmap myBitmap;
    String path;
    ImageView iv;
    int count = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);
        View viewToLoad = LayoutInflater.from(Second.this.getParent()).inflate(R.layout.second, null);
        Second.this.setContentView(viewToLoad);
        Button btn = (Button)viewToLoad.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        iv = (ImageView)viewToLoad.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        path = preferences.getString("data", "");
        File imgFile = new  File(path);
        if(imgFile.exists()){

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),  "" + path, 1000).show();

            myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
            iv.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

        }

        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
              @Override 
              public void onClick(View v) {
                  ABCGroup.group.back();
              }
            });

    }

     @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
         super.onBackPressed();
          Intent intent = new Intent(Second.this, Tab1.class);
          Tab1 parentActivity = (Tab1)getParent();  
          parentActivity.replaceContentView("Profile", new Intent(Second.this, Tab1.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY ) ); 


        }
     public void onResume()
       {
           super.onResume();

       }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got the answer

```
public void onResume()
       {
           super.onResume();

           SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
           path = preferences.getString("data", "");
           imgFile = new  File(path);
           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "" + path, 2000).show();
           if(imgFile.exists())
           {
               myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
               iv.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
           }
       }
```